# How can I monitor memory usage of container vm running on GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, memory-management, google-compute-engine, monitoring, google-container-optimized-os

I've created new VM with docker container. This VM uses Google Container-Optimized OS. How can I monitor memory usage of this instance?

There is no memory usage in observability:
[image]

I see following message in Monitoring:
[image: Monitoring]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable monitoring when you create an instance:

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-name \
    --image-family cos-stable \
    --image-project cos-cloud \
    --metadata=google-monitoring-enabled=true
```

You can also enable monitoring on an existing instance:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-name \
    --metadata=google-monitoring-enabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I see compute metrics in Monitoring Metrics Explorer.
List of metrics: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute

Comment: Just as a comment: You still won't be able to see memory metrics on the Compute Engine dashboard, you will need to go to the Monitoring Metrics Explorer as Ilya mentioned.

Comment: @josue.0 this solution is not working for me, Enabled `google-monitoring-enabled` is not working for me. Still **Not Applicable** in monitoring dashboard and not able to monitor memory or other usage of my container. I create a detail thread please check it [Monitor COS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72836884/gcp-cloud-monitoring-for-container-optimized-os)